# If death of a person is pre-determined and prarabdh then why is suicide not a part of it?

Tags: karma, death, paap, suicide

When a person commits suicide it is seen negatively but death its reason and medium are pre-determined so why is suicide considered free will?

Comment: Suicide does not grant you moksha, neither bring anything good to the people in the world. Suicide always follows a life back again. So what do you gain from it?

In the worst case, suicide while suffering from extreme depression, and sadness causes bondage to the material world that is even worse. It harms others after that. There is absolutely nothing good in suicide. 

It is totally false that *prarabdha karma* exists, it is just for ignorant people to understand the essence how re-incarnation works. Wise know, self is everything in the world.

Comment: I thought prarabadh karma is very important to Hinduism and determines why some of us suffers while some others enjog in this birth.

Comment: For those who are enlightened, there is no prarabdha karma. For them - suffering and prosperity is same and they treat both equally. Pl check Nadabindu Upanishad: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/thirty-minor-upanishads/d/doc217069.html#:~:text=Therefore%20the%20word%20pr%C4%81rabdha%20is%20accepted%20to%20enlighten%20the%20ignorant%20(only). Furthermore, for those who are enlightened, they break the laws of karma and get liberated. For them - law of karma works no more.

Comment: Also, check the first 10 verses of Ashtavakra Gita - **right or wrong, pleasure or pain exists in the mind only.**  - https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Ashtavakra-Gita-ebook.pdf

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I am asking for normal people not enlightened people as they are exception.

Comment: For normal people - during the death, the soul tries to find a body that will/has a life similar to the person dying. For example - if the person dying has a lust of money during his death, he'll be reborn into a very rich house, but he may/may not be happy or prosperous. [Manas is carried by the soul during death.]